# Could not open ServletContext resource [/jdbc.properties] after switch to Java 1.8-Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have two Spring Projects, Backend and Frontend. The Upgrade of backend was trouble-free (Spring 4.1.2.RELEASE). While deploying the frontend i have this Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [acn.spring.config.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/jdbc.properties]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:489)
....
Caused by: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/jdbc.properties]
```

This is the WebAppInitializer for Frontend:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig.class };
    }
    .....
```

Appconfig is in backend project and looks like this:

```
@Import(DataConfig.class)
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   ...
}
```

The missing property file is used in DataConfig which is imported here:

```
@PropertySource("jdbc.properties")
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
   ...
}
```

Why could not the property file not be found?

EDIT: Jar structure of the backend:

- META-INF

  - MANIFEST.MF
  - maven
- mySourcePackages Structure
- jdbc.properties

War structure of the frontend:

- META-INF

  - MANIFEST.MF
  - maven
- resources
- WEB-INF

  - classes

    - mySourcePackages Structure
  - jsp
  - lib

    - all the jars including backend.jar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tell the configuration class that your properties is in the classpath. Otherwise, it will look in the Servlet context by default since it's a web context.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `jdbc.properties` is in the root of your classpath. If that's not the problem I'd need more details on your problem, like what's your folder structure and if you compile-package to a war.

Comment: jdbc.properties is in the root of the backend (directly under resources). And it can be read in backend. It could be read also from frontend before this upgrade..  When i package the frontend, the war consists of 3 folders META-INF (MANIFEST.MF and maven folder which has the pom.xml etc.) + resources (my frontend files like css, js.. which are under webapp folder) + WEB-INF (classes, jsp and lib folders, lib contains all the jars including the backend.jar). When i extract the backend jar, jdbc.properties is at the base folder, along with the META-INF etc.